# SSH connect with key

Tags: authentication, ssh, private-key, public-key

I am trying to connect (to localhost now just for test purpose) using public/private key pair but I am unsuccesful at the moment.

Here is what i have done so far:

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa` 
   (no passphrase and store the key in `id_rsa` (private) and `id_rsa.pub` (public)
2. Set permissions

   ```
   chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh
   chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa*
   ```
3. Copied `id_rsa.pub` content to `authorized_keys` and added permission `chmod 600`

Now when I try to log in with `ssh username@localhost` it still asks me for a password.

Am I doing something wrong?

The system i work on is Scientific Linux 6.4 (Carbon)

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your system's log.

Let me show you an example, if I've my home directory with a `0777` mask, `sshd` will refuse to log me and I can find why in the `/var/log/auth.log` file (I'm on an Ubuntu 15.04 workstation):

```
Jul 30 13:14:04 hostname sshd[16232]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/max
Jul 30 13:14:05 hostname sshd[16232]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
```

You should specify your Operating System in order to have a more focused answer.

Comment: I can't find those logs. It may be because i don't have access to root (and I won't have).

Comment: The system i work on is Scientific Linux 6.4 (Carbon)

Comment: @EmilRojewski Scientific Linux, as fas as I know, is based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, so the log should be `/var/log/secure`, but in that case it's readable only by `root`.